# ToListAsync in ASP.NET MVC Core and Entity Framework not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code in ASP.NET MVC Core and Entity Framework and I get the following error when I do a `ToListAsync`.

> Additional information: The source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources
>   that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework
>   asynchronous operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

This is my code:

```
var states = mDbContext.State.ToListAsync();
var countries = mDbContext.Country.ToListAsync();

mMemoryCache.Set(Countries, await countries,
    new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.MaxValue));
mMemoryCache.Set(States, await states,
   new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.MaxValue));
```

My context class extends from `DbContext`, and I used EF 6.

```
public virtual DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<State> State { get; set; }
```

Any idea why I can't perform `ToListAsync()` even when I have everything installed?

Comment: Is your code really `public virtual DbSet State { get; set; }`?

Comment: Yes, in the context class which inherits from DbContext.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL perhaps?

Comment: No, MS SQL server

Comment: 1) Which .net framework you are using in project.json? 2) have you added `System.Data.Entity;` in your controller/class?

Comment: .net4.5.2. Yes, I have system.data.entityand still have the error.

Answer (score 41):

`ToListAsync()` is defined in both `System.Data.Entity` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. If you import both, it will default to the definition in System.Data.Entity generating the above error. Remove `System.Data.Entity` and add try adding using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`;

Comment: This should be a comment as it does not answer the question nor explains why this would help.

Comment: Ironically, it helped me in an unrelated issue

Comment: +1 This answer resolved the exact same " IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable" error for me as well. I wish MS had been smarter about organizing their libraries or at least created more useful error messages after adding EfCore..

Comment: This helped me in the process of converting an ASP.NET 4.5 project to .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Basically to use `ToList()` you need `using System.Linq;` and to use `ToListAsync()` you need `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Answer (score 4):

EF6 != EF Core. They are feature similar to some extent but they are not compatible.

ToListAsync is an EF Core feature and you're trying to use it on an EF6 DbContext.

That's why it doesn't work. If you want to use this feature you have to use an EF Core DbContext - but then again you might be using EF6 only features elsewhere in your code, and those would stop working instead.